# Space-between elements in container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I have a container with label text and checkboxes, now this is what I currently have

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: fit-content;
  margin: 0 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container.firstCheck{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.container.secondCheck{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="checkboxes">
    <div class="firstCheck">
      <label for="check1">this is 1</label>
      <input name="check1" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
    <div class="SecondCheck">
      <label for="check2">this is 2</label>
      <input name="check2" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

now I want the label to be at the far left of the container and the checkbox to be at the far right of the container **using flexbox**. This illustrates my goal
[image: imgur].

PS: I also want to be able to **reduce** html tags if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

minimal solution

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.checkbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="check1">this is 1</label>
    <input name="check1" type="checkbox" />
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="check2">this is 2</label>
    <input name="check2" type="checkbox" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `justify-content: space-between` to place the items on the left and right of the container. 
Also, you need to correct the SecondCheck name in `CSS`. In the `HTML` structure, it has capital 'S' while in `CSS` it has small 's'. 
I have corrected it in my answer.
Hope this helps, Thanks!!

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container {
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    width: 200px;
    height: fit-content;
    margin: 0 10px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border:2px solid #000;
 }

.container.firstCheck{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.container.SecondCheck{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.firstCheck{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.checkboxes{
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
}
.firstCheck, .SecondCheck{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="checkboxes">
    <div class="firstCheck">
      <label for="check1">this is 1</label>
      <input name="check1" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
    <div class="SecondCheck">
      <label for="check2">this is 2</label>
      <input name="check2" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `flex` on `.firstCheck,` and `.SecondCheck` then set `margin-left: auto` on `input`. I removed some useless codes, check it out below:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.checkboxes {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.firstCheck input, .SecondCheck input {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.firstCheck, .SecondCheck {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="checkboxes">
    <div class="firstCheck">
      <label for="check1">this is 1</label>
      <input name="check1" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
    <div class="SecondCheck">
      <label for="check2">this is 2</label>
      <input name="check2" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done as follows:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 200px;
  height: 140px;  
  border: solid 2px #ccc;
}

.divcheck {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="divcheck">
      <label for="check1">this is 1</label>
      <input name="check1" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
    <div class="divcheck">
      <label for="check2">this is 2</label>
      <input name="check2" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply `flex` properties to the elements that you want to position, like this:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: fit-content;
  margin: 0 10px;
  /*       justify-content: space-around; */
}

.checkboxes {
  width: 100%;
}

.firstCheck {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.secondCheck{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.firstLabel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.secondLabel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="checkboxes">
    <div class="firstCheck">
      <label class="firstLabel" for="check1">this is 1</label>
      <input class="firstInput" name="check1" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
    <div class="secondCheck">
      <label class="secondLabel" for="check2">this is 2</label>
      <input class="secondInput" name="check2" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the container has some padding from your space-around applied css that you have to remove in order to create some space for the first&second check divs. You don't actually need the display flex for container div.

You should actually set both checks **position: relative;** and move your checkbox to right using **position: absolute;** and **right: 0px;**

You can reduce the number of classes by replacing the firstCheck and secondCheck with a simple **.check** class or whatever you want it to be. You can style them individually using the **:nth-of-type(n)** without having to assign a class or id to each of them.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="checkboxes">
    <div class="check">
      <label for="check1">this is the first and longer label spread on 2 rows</label>
      <input name="check1" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
    <div class="check">
      <label for="check2">this is 2</label>
      <input name="check2" type="checkbox"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px 60px 10px 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.checkboxes { 
  width: 100%;
}
.checkboxes .check {
  position: relative;
}

.checkboxes .check input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px; /* the checkbox is normally positioned at the end of the last row of a label, this positions it in line with the first one */
  right: -30px; /* just to make sure the label wont be too close to the checkbox */

}
```

Here's a codePen for you to see how it works: https://codepen.io/ialexandru/pen/YzPvGPR

Answer (score 0):

You can use grid if you want less divs

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  width: 200px;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}
.child {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <div class="child">label</div>
      <div class="child"><input type="checkbox" /></div>
      <div class="child">label</div>
      <div class="child"><input type="checkbox" /></div>
    </div>
```